# How to tell if a package is part of deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, react-scripts

I have a react application. I'm using react-scripts build. As I understand ([from this link](https://www.matthewburfield.com/do-npm-dependencies-and-dev-dependecies-effect-your-production-build/)), the package-lock.json doesn't affect the build and the build will take any packages it needs that are imported in the files (regardless if they are dev dependencies or not). How can I check if a certain package was installed on a deployed environment? The reason why I'm asking is that we want to verify that no dev dependencies or any of it sub dependencies are part of deployment to customers.

Comment: set `NODE_ENV` env var to `production` before executing `npm install`, this will install only dependencies. eg; `NODE_ENV=production npm install` or `export NODE_ENV=production; npm i`

Comment: But for deployment we're using nyc react-scripts build and not npm install

Comment: then how you are installing deps in production, common scenario goes like this.
clone/pull repo, then `npm  install` after that `npm run build.` is this same for you ?

Comment: In dev dependencies we have dependencies that are used for creating the build but not used in the application. They are defined as dev dependencies, therefore if we use npm install production they won't be installed and build will fail (for example node-sass). We can't move them to dependencies because we scan our code for vulnerabilities and these packages have vulnerabilities which will result in false positive of application having this issue because they aren't used anywhere in code.

Comment: so you want to make sure build folder doesn't contain any code that is from dev-dep packages ?, is that correct ?. if so I think it  wont be there since you are not importing/requiring those packages in your code and js bundlers will omit those packages in final build.

Comment: That is correct. Since the project is big and has multiple teams working on it, I can't guarantee no developer will import them, and that's my concern, that someone will make a mistake, like move an imported package to the dev-dependencies and then we won't know we are exposed to this vulnerability. That's why I'm looking for a way to check what packages are used at production

Comment: since package.json is just a JSON file you can import it in JS & do all lookup stuffs so does this solves issue you ? (May be you already know this but I still like to point it out)